# are there any BI software with Cloud Firestore for Google Firebase Integration

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, powerbi

I'm looking for a way to use cloud firestore data to make reports and rundowns for the business side of our team. However, I cant find a way to use our actual document and collection data in any sort of analytics way. All searches point me to big query which uses more user activity data than any of our actual data in cloud firestore. Are there any BI solutions for this? or is there any way for me to make an easy way for them to make reports on this data?

Comment: BI generally requires complex quering, and even though firebase is a fantastic database, it's querying capabilities are lesser than that of SQL database, hence everyone recommends Big Query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore does not have aggregate query capabilities, so most often it's a good idea to connect your data to a more powerful query engine like BigQuery. There are two ways to do this with Firestore:

1. Use the [Export Collections to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-bigquery-export) extension to constantly sync data from Firestore to BigQuery.
2. Manually export data from Firestore and [load the export into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore).

Either of these approaches will give you all the rich querying capabilities of BigQuery for your Firestore data.